# amsthm: \newtheoremstyle, headspace, \mbox{}, and lists

Tags: lists, line-breaking, theorems, amsthm

Q: How do I define a `newtheoremstyle` which will start the theorem text on a `newline` after the header **even when** the theorem text starts with a list, e.g., `enumerate`? If there's no way of doing this, will any reasonable hacks get the job done?

You can see below in theorem 2.1 that my `newtheoremstyle`, `theorem-break`, does as desired when the theorem text does **not** start with a list environment. But you can see in theorem 2.2. that theorem text starting with a list environment will eat up the `\newline`. The `\mbox{}` hack in theorem 2.3 sort of works, but adds an unnecessary blank line (compare with theorem 1.3).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem-plain}{Theorem}[section] 
\newtheoremstyle{break}  % follow `plain` defaults but change HEADSPACE.
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {\newline}  % HEADSPACE. `plain` default: {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem-break}{Theorem}[section] 
\begin{document}

  \section{Plain Theorems}

  \begin{theorem-plain}[foo]
    Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor.
  \end{theorem-plain}

  \begin{theorem-plain}[foo]
    \begin{itemize}
      \item foo
      \item bar
    \end{itemize}
    Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor.
  \end{theorem-plain}

  \begin{theorem-plain}[foo]
    \mbox{}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item foo
      \item bar
    \end{itemize}
    Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor.
  \end{theorem-plain}

  \section{Theorems with Linebreaks after header}

  \begin{theorem-break}[foo]
    Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor. 
  \end{theorem-break}

  \begin{theorem-break}[foo]
    \begin{itemize}
      \item foo
      \item bar
    \end{itemize}  
    Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor.
  \end{theorem-break}

  \begin{theorem-break}[foo]
    \mbox{}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item foo
      \item bar
    \end{itemize}
    Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor.
  \end{theorem-break}

\end{document}
```

[image: theorems]

Comment: Would using `ntheorem` instead of `amsthm` be an option?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46357/how-to-suppress-vertical-space-between-theorem-heads-and-enumitem-environments/46391#46391

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I suppose so? I'm going through the documentation. A little difficult for me to understand how to use it.

Comment: @brianjd: see my answer below; `ntheorem` offers a predefined `break` style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If using `ntheorem` instead of `amsthm` is an option (see [Theorem packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5599/3954)), then you can use the predefined style `break`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{theorem-plain}{Theorem}[section] 
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem-break}{Theorem}[section] 

\begin{document}

  \section{Plain Theorems}

  \begin{theorem-plain}[foo]
    Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor.
  \end{theorem-plain}

  \begin{theorem-plain}[foo]
    \begin{itemize}
      \item foo
      \item bar
    \end{itemize}
    Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor.
  \end{theorem-plain}

  \section{Theorems with Linebreaks after header}

  \begin{theorem-break}[foo]
    Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor. 
  \end{theorem-break}

  \begin{theorem-break}[foo]
    \begin{itemize}
      \item foo
      \item bar
    \end{itemize}  
    Lorem ipsum sit amet dolor.
  \end{theorem-break}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this approach and it worked. I'll probably stick with this. One nice thing about this approach is that it works for environments in `paralist` as well (the previous `makeatletter` approach did not). Passing `ntheorem` the `amsthm` and `thmmarks` options and loading `ntheorem` before `amsmath` were all critical to getting the output I wanted.

Answer (score 11):

The code given in  [How to suppress vertical space between theorem heads and enumitem environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46357/how-to-suppress-vertical-space-between-theorem-heads-and-enumitem-environments/46391#46391) almost works in this case but `amsthm` seems to require slightly different space correction otherwise the first item looks too close to the heading to me, try adding this to the preamble after the loading of the packages

```
\makeatletter
\def\enumfix{%
\if@inlabel
 \noindent \par\nobreak\vskip-\topsep\hrule\@height\z@
\fi}

\let\olditemize\itemize
\def\itemize{\enumfix\olditemize}

\makeatother
```

Comment: Thx David. This worked. Although, very mysterious to me. I never understand the internal stuff too well.

Answer (score 2):

Input an explicit space (`\` followed by a space) after header, for example

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proposition}[header]\ 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item first
            \item second
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{proposition}
\end{document}
```