# Enumerate alignment problem in theorem environment

Tags: lists, theorems, enumerate, amsart

I'm using amsart. When I create an enumeration inside a theorem environment, the numbering is not aligned properly:

```
Theorem 14. (1)
(2)
(3)
(4)
```

How do I shift the (2),(3),... to be aligned with (1)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A simple solution is to use `\ ` before `\begin{enumerate}`. It would align (1) with the other items.

Comment: @Guido, I see it works. But that leaves a blank line.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46357/how-to-suppress-vertical-space-between-theorem-heads-and-enumitem-environments/46391#46391  and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51701/amsthm-newtheoremstyle-headspace-mbox-and-lists/51710#51710

Comment: Your theorems won't have their text indented so that each lines starts at the right of the "Theorem n" label, so also this one shouldn't. Three possibilities (in order of personal preference): add some words before the `enumerate`; leave as `amsart` does; add `\mbox{}` before the `enumerate` (similar to what Guido suggests).

Answer (score 39):

The "official" AMS suggestion, presented in a [FAQ entry](http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=205), is to follow `\begin{thm}` with the command `\leavevmode`.
this will leave the theorem header on a line by itself.

**edit:** the `amsthm` documentation has undergone a thorough revision.  the new version (`amsthdoc.pdf`) is on ctan and will be included in tex live 2015.  more "elaborate" possibilities are suggested for this situation in the updated manual.

Comment: Thanks! PS: It would be wonderful it it could be automated (and by default). Something like the following pseudocode: " if(enumerate or itemize follows \begin{environment}) then: insert \leavevmode "

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth-\widthof{\the\csname thm@headfont\endcsname Theorem \thethm. }}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item Item 1 this is meant to fill in the line till the end of line until it breaks in to second line.
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate}%
\end{minipage}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

Using `linegoal` package to calculate the length of the minipage:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{enumitem,linegoal}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linegoal}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item Item 1 this is meant to fill in the line till the end of line until it breaks in to second line.
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate}%
\end{minipage}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I add `\usepackage[unicode,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}` item is not in a line with theorem. How can I repair?

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to reduce the distance between the theorem and the list?

Comment: Did you try? I get `Overfull \hbox (69.44412pt too wide)` and, if the item text wraps, it will go beyond the right margin.

Comment: @egreg: that is obviously that the box is too wide if there will be long lines ... And if there are long lines then the minipagewidth has to be corrected.

Comment: @bob: for example  `\begin{thm}\hspace{-1em}\begin{mini...}`

Comment: @egreg: I know! But I do not like complicated solutions if one do not need it. And for short item lines you do not need it!

Comment: I don't like *incorrect* solutions. At least add `\hfuzz=\maxdimen`, so the user won't be bothered with a (not so) spurious warning.

Comment: @Herbert When I add `\usepackage[unicode,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}` item is not in a line with theorem. How can I repair?

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{thm}
$\ $
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}
```

shows

```
Theorem 14. 
(1) Item 1
(2) Item 2
(3) Item 3
```

Comment: The question asked to put (1) on the same line as the theorem header and align the next items below it, so this is not really an answer to the question.