# Theorem Spacing in Lists

Tags: spacing, lists, theorems, enumitem

I was wondering how I can change the spacing in my lists when I start my list off with a theorem environment. An example of this is that I have my list using the enumitem package with my code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item
     \begin{scrapwork}
     ...
     \end{scrapwork}
     \begin{proof}
     ...
     \end{proof}
\end{enumerate}
```

Which outputs with my theorem environment (scrapwork) starting on the line after where my item label is.

What I would have liked to happen is for Scrapwork and Proof to be aligned while placing scrapwork on the same line as my item label.

Thank you.

EDIT: MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,enumitem}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{scrapwork}{Scrapwork}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item
\begin{scrapwork}
wordshere
\end{scrapwork}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Will http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73747/11232 be useful?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. A MWE begins with `\documentclass{}` and ends with `\end{document}` and shows precisely where the error is...

Comment: @HarishKumar It is actually the opposite of that. I am trying to embed the theorem environment in a list instead of a list in the theorem environment.

Also I updated the post with a MWE.

Comment: @Dvorac You probably want `\swapnumbers` from the `amsthm` packages: so you declare `scrapwork` as a numbered theorem and the number will precede "Scrapwork".

Comment: I agree with @Dvorac: this is *not* a duplicate, so I voted for reopening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take shelter inside a `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,enumitem}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{scrapwork}{Scrapwork}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linegoal}
\begin{scrapwork}
wordshere
\end{scrapwork}
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If it's really the same, I'd prefer this question to be closed as duplicate instead of answered.

Comment: So it was the same. Should be closed, sorry.