# Itemizing theorem body

Tags: theorems, itemize, amsthm

Using package `amsthm`, the desired theorem style achieved,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}{}{}{}{}{\bf}{}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem*{mythm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{mythm}
This is a normal body text.
\end{mythm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But itemizing the body makes trouble,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}{}{}{}{}{\bf}{}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem*{mythm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{mythm}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This an itemized body text.
        \item This an itemized body text.
    \end{itemize}
\end{mythm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As the last output shows, first item has jumped to the head line.

**How can I bring it back to the body?**

Comment: potential duplicate: [Enumerate alignment problem in theorem environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74098/579)

Comment: Actually this is not a duplicate. I do not want to align items with what is on head line.

Comment: Use `\leavevmode` before `\begin{itemize}`

Comment: @Shaqpad -- the use of `\leavevmode` is exactly what that answer recommends, as christian has repeated.  items are *not* aligned with the head line, but treated as a "usual" list.  i'll add an example to the cited answer to make this clear.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: `leavevmode` is not enough, as there will be a spurious vertical space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with `enumitem`. One can define a `thmitemise` clone, which incorporates by default the given setup, to avoid having to type it each time it is used:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm} \newtheoremstyle{mystyle}{}{}{}{}{\bf}{}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem*{mythm}{Theorem}
\usepackage{enumitem, showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{mythm}
    \begin{itemize}[wide=0.5em, leftmargin =*, nosep, before = \leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
        \item This an itemized body text.
        \item This an itemized body text.
    \end{itemize}
\end{mythm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

here is a mechanism for removing the extra space between the theorem head
and the list.  i don't really like it, but it will provide necessary
information to make this a feature of the ams theorem facility when that
is overhauled.  (latex doesn't make things like this easy.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
\leavevmode
\makeatletter
\@nobreaktrue
\makeatother
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Possibly the easiest solution is `hfill`

```
\begin{theorem} 
\hfill
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
```

Answer (score 3):

An even easier solution may be this:

```
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{mythm}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
   \item[]
   \item state 1
   \item state 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{mythm}
```