# Seeking an explanation for the code of the theorem style "break" in the package "ntheorem"

Tags: macros, spacing, amsthm

In the package `ntheorem`, there is a theorem style called `break`, the corresponding code defining it reads:

```
\newtheoremstyle{break}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
          ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
  {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
          ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}
```

I adopted this code to make it work with `amsthm`, below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{break}
    {}{}
    {\normalfont}{}
    {\bfseries}{}
    {0pt}
    {%
        \rlap{\vbox{\hbox{%
            \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\nobreakspace #2}%
            {\thmnote{\hspace{.4em}$($#3$)$}}%
        }\hbox{\strut}\vskip0pt}}%
    }

\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

Text

\begin{theorem}
    \blindtext
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item text
        \item text
        \item text
    \end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This works perfectly and in particular works when the theorem begins with a list, which is not the case for the simple definition given in the `amsthm` manual:

```
\newtheoremstyle{break}%
  {}{}%
  {\itshape}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}%  % Note that final punctuation is omitted.
  {\newline}{}
```

> The main problem with this simple one is that when the theorem begins with an `itemize` or `enumerate` list, one would have to write `\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}`, see @Mico's nice answer below. A friend of mine strongly advise me to make this automatic. Also, if one writes this in an article, when the template changes, one would have to manually remove those `\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}`, and even though this can be done by defining it as a separate macro and redefining it each time, it is definitely not simple and elegant.

My question is:

1. How does this code (I mean the one in the MWE, adopted from `ntheorem`) work? I'm not familiar with these plain TeX macros so I don't quite understand what is going on here.
2. You may notice that I added a `\vskip0pt` after `\hbox{\strut}`, which surprisingly adds some extra vertical space after the theorem heading (which is exactly what I wanted, though I don't know why this happens). Why would this happen?

Comment: @Mico Yes, as I have stated in the question, the code there does not work well when the theorem begins with an `itemize` or `enumerate` list, one would still have to manually add `\leavevmode` or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Section 4.3.1 of the user guide of the [amsthm](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package is entitled "Theorem style break". I'll quote it here in its entirety [highlighting added]:

[image]
[image]

---

To summarize, inserting the instructions `\leavevmode` and `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` right before `\begin{enumerate}` fixes the problem. It's not sufficient to insert just `\leavevmode`.

Speaking for myself, I think that executing `\leavevmode \vspace{-\baselineskip}` if and when necessary is easier than to try to adapt some code from the `ntheorem` package. The `ntheorem` and `amsthm` packages may share similar user-level commands such `\newtheorem` and `\theoremstyle`, but they are very different "under the hood".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{break}% % see section 4.3.1 of amsthm user guide
   {}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{}{\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{breakthm}{Theorem}

\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{breakthm}
    \lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{breakthm}

\begin{breakthm} 
    \leavevmode \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{itemize}[nosep] % 'nosep' is optional
        \item text
        \item text
        \item text
    \end{itemize}
\end{breakthm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this and am always using this method. But a friend of mine strongly advise me to make this automatically. Also, if I write this in the article, when the template changes, I would have to remove this `\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}`, and even though this can be done by defining it as a separate macro and redefining it each time, it is definitely not simple and elegant.

Comment: Aren't amsthm theorems still just single item lists? Thus issuing `\iten` starts a new line (not at pc, so haven't tested on this example)

Comment: @Jinwen - It would have been useful to state this information explicitly, in the body of the query.

Comment: @daleif - Inserting an `\item` instruction will create a line break. However, it will also insert an inordinate amount of vertical whitespace; that's the problem alluded to in the excerpt from the user guide shown above.

Comment: At least some of these use a zero item spacing. So I haven't had issues with it. Ahh well

Comment: @Mico Sorry for not mentioning this. But your answer is great, even though I've been using `\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}`, it didn't occur to me that it has been officially mentioned in the guide. Continuing my previous remark, I think from this perspective the code in `ntheorem` works better (of course the `\newtheoremstyle` there is different, but the core code can be adopted as the MWE in the question) than the simple one in `amsthm`. One may argue about the page breaking issue, but I've also experienced page breaks after the theorem heading with the `amsthm` version.

Comment: @Jinwen - The page breaking issue you mention is also mentioned, along with a suggestion for how to fix it, in the user guide of the `amsthm` package.

Comment: @Mico Thank you. I'm aware of this and I was writing this to argue that the adopted complex version's (possible page breaking after the heading) problem also happens with the simple version.

Comment: This answer is relevant re avoiding the page break problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307199