# How can I get the correct align

Tags: vertical-alignment, lists

I copy this code from [Enumerate alignment problem in theorem environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73741/enumerate-alignment-problem-in-theorem-environment)
and add `\usepackage[unicode,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{}[section]
\usepackage[unicode,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\section{My theorem}
\begin{thm}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problemThis is a problem This is a problem  This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problemThis is a problem This is a problem
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

I got
[image]

The number 1.1 doesn't align with item (a).

If I remove `\usepackage[unicode,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}`, I got correct align
[image]

How can I get the correct align?

Comment: `hyperref` puts the anchor above the list, hence the extra vertical space. If no anchor is needed, you can wrap the first `\item` in the list (or the entire `enumerate` or the `minipage` environments) in a `NoHyper` environment.

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much. You can write answer and I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hyperref` package puts the anchor above the list, hence the extra vertical space. If no anchor is needed, you can wrap the first `\item` in the list or the entire `enumerate` or the `minipage` environments in a `NoHyper` environment. The following MWE is with the `enumerate` wrapped in `NoHyper`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{}[section]
\usepackage[unicode,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
    \section{My theorem}
    \begin{thm}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
           \begin{NoHyper}
            \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
                \item This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problemThis is a problem This is a problem  This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problemThis is a problem This is a problem
                \item Item 2
                \item Item 3
            \end{enumerate}
          \end{NoHyper} 
        \end{minipage}
    \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: this has a small problem -- using `\linewidth` as the width of the minipage makes this too wide by the width of the theorem label.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because `hyperref` packages redefines the macro and puts anchor for cross referencing. I would prefer the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{}[section]
\usepackage[unicode,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
\section{My theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{thm}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip},rightmargin=\leftmargin]
\item This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problemThis is a problem This is a problem  This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problem This is a problemThis is a problem This is a problem
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{thm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

In the example, I have used `enumitem` package instead of `enumerate`.

Comment: unfortunately, the theorem label is just a bit lower than the first line of the text of item (1).  on the other hand, the width of the enumerated paragraph is good.