# Indentation of list in a theorem environment

Tags: spacing, lists, theorems

Typically, the body in a theorem environment begins on the same line as the heading.  If the text begins with a list, the first line looks a little funny due to the indentation before the label.

I'm feeling too lazy to figure out how to put in an image myself. I'm talking about the effect in Theorem 1.2 [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51701/amsthm-newtheoremstyle-headspace-mbox-and-lists/51710#51710); compare to Theorem 1.1 at the same link.

I *don't* want to address this issue by making the text start on the next line (as in the linked question).  Instead, I'd like for the first item not to be indented, i.e., the label of the first item should appear in the same position that the first letter would appear if the body began with text.

I'm using `amsthm` and `enumitem`, if it matters.

Answer (score 4):

This is the recommendation given in the AMS author FAQ:

```
\begin{theorem}
\hangindent\leftmargini
\textup{(1)}\hskip\labelsep First item.
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\item ...
```

If the environment is `itemize` rather than `enumerate`, replace the first line by

```
$\bullet$\hskip\labelsep First item.
```

If the first item has multiple paragraphs, simulate the paragraph breaks by inserting
an explicit line break and indenting:

```
... First item.\\
\indent Next paragraph ...
```

There is some additional commentary in the [FAQ entry](http://www.ams.org/faq?faq_id=206).

Comment: Not very satisfying, but I see in the FAQ entry that the space is defined too deeply inside LaTeX to be easily changed.

Comment: @MarkMeckes -- thanks for noticing the reason in the faq entry.  when i write one of these faq entries, i try to say *why* something happens the way it does; this usually isn't encouraged, since it often makes faq entries rather long, but i think it can help someone looking for the "best" answer (and you've just given my method a vote of confidence).  if you find a better way, please feel free to send it on, to `tech-support@ams.org`.

Comment: Personally I find the "why"s very helpful -- please go on writing them!