# \linebreak in theorem style

Tags: line-breaking, theorems

I would like something like this [amsthm: \newtheoremstyle, headspace, \mbox{}, and lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51701/amsthm-newtheoremstyle-headspace-mbox-and-lists)
but also with an indent after the new line, as if I wrote ~ and pressed enter twice. Ideally without ntheorem. I tried

```
\newtheoremstyle{break}  % follow `plain` defaults but change HEADSPACE.
{\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
{\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
{\itshape}  % BODYFONT
{0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
{\bfseries} % HEADFONT
{.}         % HEADPUNCT
{\linebreak}  % HEADSPACE. `plain` default: {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
{}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
```

but this gives a weird error about a number missing.
A sub question is what LaTeX command gives the same result as pressing enter twice?

Comment: a compilable example would really help here.  also, try `\newline` instead of `\linebreak` for the next-to-last argument; that's what is generally recommended, but i don't have time to investigate why.

Comment: See the link for a compilable example, but this has \newline instead of what I want.

Comment: answer to sub-question: `\par` is the (la)tex equivalent to a blank line.  an alternate form (essentially a primitive, without all the latex addenda) is `\endgraf`; this is usable in situations where `\par` or a blank line are not "accepted".

Comment: Thanks. Although \par gives the same error in the newtheoremstyle

Comment: i took your sub-question to mean "more generally".  none of the methods i mentioned would work in a `\newtheoremstyle` definition that i'm aware of, except possibly in the last, "custom", argument.  but even there, it's questionable.  there is a "break" theorem style defined in the `amsthm` users guide, although it doesn't indent the next line.  it *does* use `\newline`.  i will experiment.