# How to suppress vertical space between proof environment heads and itemize environments?

Tags: lists, theorems, enumitem, nesting

The user 'egreg' recently helped me to suppress vertical space between theorem
heads and `enumitem` environments (such as `itemize`; see the link below). I now
have a similar problem: When a `proof` environment starts with an `itemize`,
there is too much vertical space. How can the `proof` environment be redefined
such that this space is (at least party) suppressed?

Ideally, it should be a "clean" solution, so that one can type `\begin{proof}` followed by `\begin{itemize}` and no complicated commands in-between.

By redefining the `proof` environment as a theorem, one could circumvent the
problem, but how can the q.e.d. symbol be nicely placed? Not sure if that's a
good approach.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% theorems
\newif\ifstarttheorem
\newtheoremstyle{mythmstyle}%
{0.5em}%
{0.5em}%
{}% 
{}% 
{\sffamily\bfseries\global\starttheoremtrue}% 
{}% 
{\newline}% 
{\thmname{#1}\ \thmnumber{#2}\ \thmnote{(#3)}}% 
\theoremstyle{mythmstyle}% 

% proofs
\renewcommand*\proofname{Proof}
\makeatletter% q.e.d. adjustment (posted by ???)
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont\topsep2\p@\@plus2\p@\relax
  \trivlist
\item[\hskip\labelsep
  \sffamily\bfseries #1]\mbox{}\hfill\\*\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

% suppress vertical spacing (for itemize) when newtheorems start with an environment
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60001/nested-enumerate-enumitem-interferes-with-suppressing-vertical-space-after-the
\makeatletter
\preto\itemize{%
  \if@inlabel
    \ifstarttheorem
      \mbox{}\par\nobreak\vskip\glueexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip+0.3em\relax\hrule\@height\z@
      \global\starttheoremfalse
    \fi
  \fi}
\preto\enditemize{\global\starttheoremfalse}
\makeatother

% document
\begin{document}
Let's prove something:
\begin{proof}
  \begin{align*}
    x=y,\quad y=z\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=z.
  \end{align*}
\end{proof}
Here a nicer vertical spacing:
\begin{proof}
  Just some text:
  \begin{align*}
    x=y,\quad y=z\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=z.
  \end{align*}
\end{proof}
Here a version with itemize:
\begin{proof}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item $x=y,\quad y=z\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=z.$
  \end{itemize}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following. Here the environment proof gets a new flag `\starttheoremtrue` and the name of the environment is saved inside the command `\mycurrenvir`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% theorems
\newif\ifstarttheorem
\newtheoremstyle{mythmstyle}%
{0.5em}%
{0.5em}%
{}% 
{}% 
{\sffamily\bfseries\global\starttheoremtrue}% 
{}% 
{\newline}% 
{\thmname{#1}\ \thmnumber{#2}\ \thmnote{(#3)}}% 
\theoremstyle{mythmstyle}% 

% proofs
\renewcommand*\proofname{Proof}
\makeatletter% q.e.d. adjustment (posted by ???)
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont\topsep2\p@\@plus2\p@\relax
  \trivlist
\item[\hskip\labelsep
  \sffamily\bfseries #1]\gdef\mycurrenvir{proof}\global\starttheoremtrue\mbox{}\hfill\\*\ignorespaces
}{%
 \gdef\mycurrenvir{\relax}
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

% suppress vertical spacing (for itemize) when newtheorems start with an environment
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60001/nested-enumerate-enumitem-interferes-with-suppressing-vertical-space-after-the
\makeatletter
\preto\itemize{%
  \if@inlabel
    \ifstarttheorem
      \mbox{}\par\nobreak\vskip\glueexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip+0.3em\relax\hrule\@height\z@
      \global\starttheoremfalse%
    \fi%
  \fi%
 \def\tempa{proof}%
 \ifx\tempa\mycurrenvir
    \ifstarttheorem
      \mbox{}\par\nobreak\vskip\glueexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip+0.3em\relax\hrule\@height\z@
      \global\starttheoremfalse%
    \fi%
 \fi%
}
\preto\enditemize{\global\starttheoremfalse}
\makeatother

% document
\begin{document}
Let's prove something:
\begin{proof}
  \begin{align*}
    x=y,\quad y=z\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=z.
  \end{align*}
\end{proof}
Here a nicer vertical spacing:
\begin{proof}
  Just some text:
  \begin{align*}
    x=y,\quad y=z\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=z.
  \end{align*}
\end{proof}
Here a version with itemize:
\begin{proof}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item $x=y,\quad y=z\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=z.$
  \end{itemize}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: works nicely with `itemize`, even using `\qedhere`.  but with `enumerate` there's still a big gap between the heading and the first item (and `\qedhere` isn't the cause).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Marco. @Barbara: Just redefine `enumerate` (as for `itemize`) and it works

Comment: Marco, if a proof environment is directly followed by an `align` environment, do you know how to suppress the space in this situation?

Comment: @MariusHofert: I would use the same redefinition.

Comment: Thanks Marco. It's a bit difficult to understand since I do not see how the trick for the `itemize` environment can be adapted to an `align`. If possible, can you give the answer in your answer, please? [I could also file a new question for this]