# How to define a proof environment which can be displayed/hidden? [combining two TeX solutions]

Tags: environments, tex-core

I once asked for a solution to suppress vertical space right after the beginning
of a proof environment; see the link (1) below. I use this quite heavily, it
works very well.

I recently asked how to hide/display solutions in an exercise; see the link (2)
below. It also works very well.

I now would like to construct a proof environment which allows for the hide/show
feature. So exactly combining the two solutions of the above problems. I tried
my best but I'm not a TeX expert... see below (I obtain: `./mini.tex:55: LaTeX Error: \env@proof@save@env undefined.`)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{showProof}% for showing proofs
\setboolean{showProof}{true}% setting the switch

\newboolean{sol}% for solution environment
\setboolean{sol}{true}% setting the switch

% proof environment which suppresses vertical space
% see (1) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66739/how-to-suppress-vertical-space-between-proof-environment-heads-and-itemize-envir
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont\topsep2\p@\@plus2\p@\relax
  \trivlist
\item[\hskip\labelsep
  \sffamily\bfseries #1]\mbox{}\hfill\\*\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

% solution environment which allows to show/hide of content
% see (2) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172404/solution-environment-via-true-false-switch?noredirect=1#172408
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{solution}[1][sol]{
  \gdef\@tmp{#1}
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{\par\noindent{\sffamily\bfseries Solution}\par\noindent\BODY}{\ignorespaces}
}[\ifthenelse{\boolean{\@tmp}}{}{\ignorespacesafterend}]
\makeatother

% trial to define proof environment with the feature that content can be
% shown/hidden (mix of the above two solutions)
\makeatletter
\RenewEnviron{proof}[1][showProof]{
  \gdef\@tmp{#1}
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{%
    \par\pushQED{\qed}%
    \normalfont\topsep2\p@\@plus2\p@\relax
    \trivlist\item[\hskip\labelsep
    \sffamily\bfseries #1]\gdef\mycurrenvir{proof}\global\starttheoremtrue\mbox{}\hfill\\*\ignorespaces
    \BODY}{\ignorespaces}
}[\ifthenelse{\boolean{\@tmp}}{%
  \gdef\mycurrenvir{\relax}
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}{\ignorespacesafterend}]
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is some statement we would like to prove: $\exp(i\pi)=-1$
\begin{proof}
  This should be displayed if and only if showProof is set to true.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very similar in nature to [How to ignore everything in the `document` environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165258/5764) where I got around the problem by defining the required commands so as to make [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ) happy. More specifically, just add `\makeatletter \providecommand{\env@proof@save@env}{} \providecommand{\env@proof@process}{} \makeatother` somewhere before using `\RenewEnviron`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can you explain why this is required or solves the problem (it wasn't necessary for the "solution environment" problem). Many thanks.

Comment: If you replace in the solution below the head by `\RenewEnviron{proof}[2][showProof]` and use `#2` instead of the hard-coded name `Proof`, then it does not work anymore (I get `Undefined control sequence ... ` with many more symbols that tex.stackexchange fails to put in a comment). Do you know why/how to fix it?

Comment: `solution` was defined using `\NewEnviron`, while `proof` was *redefined* using `\RenewEnviron`. I think the definition via `environ` works as expected... it's just a redefinition that needs a little help.

Comment: Yes, because with `\RenewEnviron{proof}[2][showProof]` your input needs to be `\begin{proof}[<opt>]{<man>}` where `<opt>` is optional (defaults to `showProof`) and `<man>` is *mandatory*. So you would need `\begin{proof}{SHoWPRooF}` in order for `#2` to be properly recognized as a "alternative" to `Proof`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working as expected, I'll open a new post.

Comment: Here is the link to the new post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173111/line-break-in-a-modified-proof-environment-with-show-hide-feature