# How to reduce vertical spacing between proof environment and enumerate environment

Tags: spacing, enumerate, enumitem

How can I reduce the space between the proof environment head and the enumerate
environment in the minimal example below?

Note: This is most likely *not* a duplicate question. Some while ago, I posted this problem here
([How to suppress vertical space between theorem heads and enumitem environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46357/how-to-suppress-vertical-space-between-theorem-heads-and-enumitem-environments)). A fix concerning nested enumerate environments was then provided under
([Nested enumerate (enumitem) interferes with suppressing vertical space after theorem heads.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60001/nested-enumerate-enumitem-interferes-with-suppressing-vertical-space-after-the)). Finally, there was a follow-up flaw, corrected under
[Weird vertical spacing problem with (adjusted) enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122018/weird-vertical-spacing-problem-with-adjusted-enumerate)
to which I refer to here. This worked for me for quite some time, but suddenly (I have no idea why), the space is too large again. I tried to adjust the `+0.3em`, but that doesn't change any vertical space.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newif\ifstarttheorem

% proofs
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66739/how-to-suppress-vertical-space-between-proof-environment-heads-and-itemize-envir/makeatletter
\makeatletter% q.e.d. adjustment (posted by ???)
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont\topsep2\p@\@plus2\p@\relax
  \trivlist
\item[\hskip\labelsep
  \sffamily\bfseries #1]\gdef\mycurrenvir{proof}\global\starttheoremtrue\mbox{}\hfill\\*\ignorespaces
}{%
 \gdef\mycurrenvir{\relax}
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

% suppress vertical spacing (for itemize) when newtheorems start with an environment
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122018/weird-vertical-spacing-problem-with-adjusted-enumerate
\makeatletter
\preto\enumerate{%
  \if@inlabel
    \ifstarttheorem
      \mbox{}\par\nobreak\vskip\glueexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip+0.3em\relax\hrule\@height\z@
    \fi
  \fi
  \global\starttheoremfalse
 \def\tempa{proof}%
 \ifx\tempa\mycurrenvir
    \ifstarttheorem
      \mbox{}\par\nobreak\vskip\glueexpr-\parskip-\baselineskip+0.3em\relax\hrule\@height\z@
    \fi
 \fi
 \global\starttheoremfalse
}
\preto\endenumerate{\global\starttheoremfalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{proof}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Proof ...
  \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

The second part of Karl's answer works, surprisingly without the `\appto`-part. However, I realized that there is a spurious (horizontal) space/indent introduced. Minimizing this example, I ended up with the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newif\ifstarttheorem

% proofs
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173158/how-to-reduce-vertical-spacing-between-proof-environment-and-enumerate-environme
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont\topsep2\p@\@plus2\p@\relax
  \trivlist\item[\hskip\labelsep\sffamily\bfseries #1]\ignorespaces\global\starttheoremtrue\mbox{}\vskip0pt\noindent
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\noindent Proof with an optional argument:
\begin{proof}[Alternative]
  Why is there a space before "Why"?
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume you don't have an `enumerate` with *every* `proof`. Why not just add a `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` or more as the first entry inside the `proof` environment?

Comment: See David Carlisle's answer to pluton on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46357/how-to-suppress-vertical-space-between-theorem-heads-and-enumitem-environments Also, modern journals can treat this automatically, so I think there must be a nice(r) solution. Furthermore, if you put the code into the journal format, you have to manually remove these spaces again -- which is why I try to keep the actual code as 'light' as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply redefine `proof`

in this way

```
\makeatletter% q.e.d. adjustment (posted by ???)
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont\topsep2\p@\@plus2\p@\relax
  \trivlist
\item[\hskip\labelsep
  \sffamily\bfseries #1]\ignorespaces\mbox{}\vskip0pt\noindent
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
```

and use `topsep=0` when calling `enumerate`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}


% proofs
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66739/how-to-suppress-vertical-space-between-proof-environment-heads-and-itemize-envir/makeatletter
\makeatletter% q.e.d. adjustment (posted by ???)
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont\topsep2\p@\@plus2\p@\relax
  \trivlist
\item[\hskip\labelsep
  \sffamily\bfseries #1]\ignorespaces\mbox{}\vskip0pt\noindent
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

% suppress vertical spacing (for itemize) when newtheorems start with an environment
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122018/weird-vertical-spacing-problem-with-adjusted-enumerate

\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{proof}
  \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt]
  \item Proof ...
  \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

Some text
\begin{proof}
Some text
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

### EDIT

A solution without `enumitem`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newif\ifstarttheorem

% proofs
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66739/how-to-suppress-vertical-space-between-proof-environment-heads-and-itemize-envir/makeatletter
\makeatletter% q.e.d. adjustment (posted by ???)
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont\topsep2\p@\@plus2\p@\relax
  \trivlist
\item[\hskip\labelsep
  \sffamily\bfseries #1]\ignorespaces\global\starttheoremtrue\mbox{}\vskip0pt\noindent
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

% suppress vertical spacing (for itemize) when newtheorems start with an environment
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122018/weird-vertical-spacing-problem-with-adjusted-enumerate
\makeatletter
\appto\enumerate{%
  \ifstarttheorem
    \vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
  \fi
  \global\starttheoremfalse
}
\preto\endenumerate{\global\starttheoremfalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{proof}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Proof ...
  \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

Some text
\begin{proof}
Some text
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this solution. But it is similar to Werner's suggestion. Also (although I used it), not many of my coauthors use `enumitem`. When they run the code with their templates, the argument `topsep` is not recognized. For this reason, I am looking for a solution which works with `enumerate` without additional arguments.

Comment: @MariusHofert Why is your question tagged `enumitem` then?

Comment: Because I use `enumitem` (with more adjustments than in the above minimal example), just not with options in the main text. I'm sorry if this has led to confusion. I thought it is clear in which direction I'm looking due to the 'history' of the problem I mentioned.

Comment: @MariusHofert If your coworkers don't have up-to-date TeX distributions, trying what you ask is hopeless; just use the standard macros for writing the document, the refinements will be done at the end.

Comment: @egreg: So there is no easy fix based on the above idea (or maybe a new one)? Hmmm... that's a bit sad. I wish I would know more about the 'techniques' behind, but if you don't see a solution, then there most likely is indeed none...

Comment: @karlkoeller: Hi Karl. I looked at the second part of your answer and it worked for me (without the `\appto`-part). It even worked together with Enrico's hide-feature (by starring the proof environment). However, in the very basic case where the proof starts with text only, I get a spurious horizontal indent. Do you know why? I updated my post with a minimal example.