# Why is \item allowed in proof environments?

Tags: errors, lists, amsthm

The other day I was typing up a proof containing a list and I accidentally wrote `\item` inside the `proof` environment (from the `amsthm` package) but outside of any list environment. To my surprise, LaTeX typeset the file without complaining! But as soon as I moved `\item` outside of the `proof` environment, LaTeX complained of a "lonely `\item`''.

So this code gives an error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Some text
\end{proof}
\item
\end{document}
```

while this code does not

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\item
Some text
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Because proofs and theorems are build via simple lists. (Might not have been such a good idea)

Comment: @daleif There is a _very good_ reason for that. Compare `\begin{proof}\begin{enumerate}\item My item\end{enumerate}\end{proof}` with `\textit{Proof.}\quad \begin{enumerate}\item My item\end{enumerate}`.

Comment: It's also allowed in `center` or `flushleft`; not that it's recommended to use it.

Comment: @tohecz : a lot of people does not like that *feature*

Comment: @daleif Well, they can just go ahead and ask a question about it, since it can of course be switched off.

Comment: @tohecz, how would you do that, especially in such a manner that `enumerate` does not add extra space at above the list

Comment: @daleif There are [many questions on this topic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=proof+enumerate), for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173158/how-to-reduce-vertical-spacing-between-proof-environment-and-enumerate-environme

Comment: But doesn't they all give `Proof` on a line of it own in all cases. I do not particularly like that - waste of space.

Comment: @daleif Well, ask a new question about it then, I'm sure that once you precisely specify what do you want, people will give a solution quickly ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All theorem-like environments, along with `center`, `flushleft`, `flushright`, `quote`, `quotation` (and some others) are implemented as lists. For instance, `center` is defined by

```
% latex.ltx, line 3965:
\def\center{\trivlist \centering\item\relax}
\def\endcenter{\endtrivlist}
```

and

```
\begin{center}
something
\item
\end{center}
```

would not raise an error, because `\item` is allowed in `trivlist` (which is the basic environment which general lists are based on), but the result would be funny.

This is done in order to ensure that lists inside these environments work properly. Also `proof` is defined with `trivlist`.

It *might* be possible to disallow `\item` in such environments, by making  `trivlist` reinstate the correct meaning for `\item`. Something like

```
\def\center{\trivlist \centering\item\relax\let\item\@itemerr}
\def\endcenter{\endtrivlist}
```

and adding to the code for `trivlist` code such as

```
\let\item\@defaultitem
```

where the `\@itemerr` and `\@defaultitem` commands are hypothetical. The kernel presently doesn't do this (and it won't, as this might break existing documents).