# How does one make the latex compiler stricter with '\item's missing an enumerate or itemize environment?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, theorems

When `\item`  is inside a theorem-type environment, but not inside an enumerate or itemize environment, LaTeX does not give an error. Is there a way to make compiling stricter so that one receives an error when this happens?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain} 

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
  Hello
  
  \item abcd 
  \item This compiles without error.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Here is the version of TeX that I'm using, if it's important:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex

restricted \write18 enabled.

entering extended mode

Processing: test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1

L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
```

Comment: The LaTeX kernel defines quite a few (dozens, probably) user-level environments -- including most (all?) theorem-like environments and the `enumerate`, `itemize`, and `description` environments -- in terms of the very-low-level `list` and `trivlist` environments. That's why placing an `\item` instruction inside a `theorem` or `lemma` environment doesn't cause an error. What you're asking for basically amounts to a major re-write of large parts of the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: I see... Oh well. Thank you!

Comment: Related question: [errors - Why is \item allowed in proof environments? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204219/why-is-item-allowed-in-proof-environments/210056#210056)

Comment: @user202729: Very informative! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try hard enough, you can probably do this:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\theoremstyle{plain} 

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/item/before}{
  \str_if_eq:VnT \@currenvir {lemma} {\errmessage{oh~no}}
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{lemma}
  Hello
  
  \item abcd 
  \item This compiles with error.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Just a proof of concept, documentation in `texdoc lthooks`.

You may want to use `\str_case` or something else (e.g. use TeX's hash table for "constant"-time checking)
if you want to check multiple environments etc. but compiling a whitelist (or a blacklist) appears to be unavoidable to me.

Comment: It's a bit slower to do this however.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this next week.

Comment: This works for me! Thank you!