# svmono: introduce more horizontal space between a user-given theorem name and the theorem contents without occasionally introducing vertical space?

Tags: theorems, vertical-spacing, sv-classes, horizontal-spacing

Continuing [How to suppress vertical space between theorem heads and enumitem environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46357/how-to-suppress-vertical-space-between-theorem-heads-and-enumitem-environments) (as opposed to them, we use a Springer class here), for all the titled theorem-like environments in our document, we wish to have a little bit more horizontal space (than the default space) separating the given title of the environment from its contents. To this end, we tried to define `\@thmcounterend` as a simple space:

```
\documentclass{svmono}% v5.10 (2021/09/08) from https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/your-publication-journey/manuscript-preparation#toc-49268 or directly from https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/20566/data/monographs
\makeatletter\def\@thmcounterend{ }\makeatother%%% Some more horizontal space after the titles of the theorem-like environments would be great. How exactly do we introduce it without occasionally introducing superfluous vertical space?
\overfullrule=1mm
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}\noindent
Good remark:
\begin{remark}[Remark title 1]
  Remark text 1.
\end{remark}
Bad remark:
\begin{remark}[Remark title 2. More words. More words. More words. More w\ldots]\label{someLabel}
  Remark text 2.
\end{remark}
\end{document}
```

The space between the environment head and the list can get large if the head's (last) line is full and a label follows. To test, compile the input with [`pdf`]`latex` to obtain

[image: vertical gap with latex or pdflatex]

The vertical gap between “w…)” and “Remark text 2” is even larger than the gap before the environment head. This is counterintuitive and unwanted: before and after a remark we should have larger vertical gaps than within a remark. We can, of course, say `\vskip-\baselineskip`, but this is hard to maintain (because it might need to be removed, e.g., if the line width or the font globally change). Any idea?

Comment: that is not vertical space, you are forcing a second line of the paragraph that is all-white

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In the viewers `okular` and `evince`, when I select the whole text via Ctrl+A, the all-white line does not get selected. So I cannot easily determine whether the all-white line contains any spaces. Anyhow, how not to introduce this all-white line when it's semantically unnecessary (in our case, even semantically harmful)?

Comment: who looks at pdf output? add `\showoutput` and look at the log: `...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x332.89723, glue set 332.89723fil
....\write1{\newlabel{someLabel}{{2}{\thepage }}[None]}
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
`  so a label and parfillskip and rightskip but no text

Answer (score 1):

never put an unguarded space into the stream, tex only removes one glue item at the end of a paragraph, so if you make 2 as here you will produce an all-white line as a final line of the paragraph if it breaks before the space.

The command is followed by `\`  or nothing depending on the style so you could locally define it to make `\`  make a single double-length space.

```
\makeatletter\def\@thmcounterend{\def\ {\hspace{6.7pt plus 3.2pt minus 2.2pt}}}\makeatother%%% Some more horizontal space after the titles of the theorem-like environments would be great. How exactly do we introduce it without occasionally introducing superfluous vertical space?
```

[image]

Comment: Thx! Checking this now on my long book. In other terms, you're putting a doubly-long space at places in which we'd have a space anyway, aren't you?

Comment: @AlbertNash yes instead of 2 spaces as you had it

Comment: Thx! In my full-length book, I use other fonts than Computer Modern. Are there any caveats with `\def\@thmcounterend{\def\ {\hspace{2\fontdimen2\font plus2\fontdimen3\font minus2\fontdimen4\font}}}`? This way, I think I'd have exactly the double space with a double stretch and a double shrink.

Comment: @AlbertNash yes although its a stretchy space anyway so exact  arithmetc not that important but that is the right thing

Comment: Seems like another approach is needed if the user does not supply a name of his/her own: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678941 . Ideas?